# How to save command line file as .txt file every time. In CMD need to display the speedtest output save the those command line as .txt file

Tags: python-3.x, networking, automation

This is the program as given below

import os
import time

1. index=0
2. file=open("out_{index}.txt", 'a')
3. while True:
4. ps=os.system(f"speedtest.exe")
5. file.append(ps)
6. index+=1
7. time.sleep(4)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is file.write() and not file.append().

I think you want to write to a new file every time.

I  would do this.

```
import time
import os
index = 0
while True:
    ps = os.system("speedtest.exe")
    with open(f"out_{index}.txt", 'w+') as f:
        f.write(ps)
    index += 1
time.sleep(4)
```

However, if you want to write in the same file.

I  would do this.

```
import time
import os
with open("out_file.txt", 'a+') as f:
index = 0
    while True:
        ps = os.system("speedtest.exe")
        f.write(ps)
        index += 1
time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: When i was this code getting error like f.write(ps)
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: @user11766050 Yes sir, I made a mistake. Please retry with the edited code. I forgot "as f" after the open function